# simple mysql regexp

Tags: mysql, regex

As the following statement indicated, it matches a string start with one or more digits following by a space. Could you explain to me why this end up with 0 instead of 1? 
However, it outputs 1 if I simply removes **^**. As I know, **^** matches the beginning of a string, didn't I use it incorrectly?
 Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT "345 boxberry ave " REGEXP '^\d*[[.space.]][[:<:]]b';
```

[edit] Basically, I want to match any street name start with 'b'.

Comment: So what do you want to match, first letter as a digit(number of digits) and followed up a space or ending with a space? You query doesn't make any sense. Why don't you show us your input strings and expected output out of it.

Comment: Then that has nothing to do with starting character being a digit, hasn't it?

Comment: It has to be because every field starts with a few digits and follow by a street name

Answer (score 1):

Replace `\d` with `[[:digit:]]`:

```
SELECT "345 boxberry ave " REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]*[[.space.]][[:<:]]b';
```

Please note also that `*` matches any sequence of zero or more a characters while `+` matches any sequence of one or more a characters. I'm not sure of your requirements but you may need to use `+` instead if the digits are required.

Comment: You probably also want to use `[[:space:]]` instead of `[[.space.]]`, to skip tabs as well.

Answer (score 1):

In simple way you can do like this:

```
 SELECT "345 boxberry ave " REGEXP '^[0-9]*[ ]+b.*'; //for begin with zero or more digits than one space and begin with character b 

 SELECT "345 boxberry ave " REGEXP '^[0-9]+[ ]+b.*'; //for begin with one or more digits
```

You can't use abbreviations like \d, \w and so on in mysql.